# Knockout: model function not firing

Tags: knockout-2.0

### Knockout model function not firing on click event

Hi Friends,

I have following html code that has the model binded to the div element "bindingDiv" :

```
<div class="clear" id="bindingDiv">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-bind="visible: Documents().length > 0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-2">
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Display Name
                    </th>
                    <th style="max-width: .5% !important; min-width: .5% !important; text-align: center;
                        width: .5% !important;">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Documents">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: Id, visible:false"></span>
                        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: DisplayName"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img class="action" title="Tools" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" src="~/Content/images/tool.png"
                            alt="tool" />
                        <div class="actions" style="display: none;">
                            <ul class="action-links" style="min-width: 75px;">
                                <li><a class="tool tool-remove" data-bind="click: $root.deleteDocument">Delete</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following is the model object:

```
function Document(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Document.Name);
    self.DisplayName = ko.observable(data.Document.DisplayName);
    self.Description = ko.observable(data.Document.Description);
    self.DocumentPath = ko.observable(data.Document.DocumentPath);
    self.DocumentTypeId = ko.observable(data.Document.DocumentTypeId);
};

var isBindingComplete = true;

function CourseDocumentModel(docs) {
    var self = this;
    self.Documents = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(docs, function (doc) { var d = new Document(doc); return d; }));

    self.addDocument = function (doc) {
        var document = new Document(doc);
        self.Documents.push(document);
    };

    self.reloadDocuments = function(docs) {
        self.Documents.removeAll();
        ko.utils.arrayMap(docs, function (doc) { self.Documents.push(new Document(doc)) });
    };

    self.deleteDocument = function(doc) {
        if (!isBindingComplete) {
            return;
        }
        alert(ko.toJSON(doc));
        var conf = true;
        conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (conf) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("DeleteDocument", Controllers.Course)/",
                data: ko.toJSON(doc),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (mydata) {
                    self.Documents.remove(doc);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("removeDocument method error status: " + xhr.status);
                    alert("removeDocument method error thrown: " + thrownError);
                }
            });                
        }
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
        refreshGrid(null);
    });

var model;

function refreshGrid(uploadRow)
{
    isBindingComplete = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetAllDocuments", Controllers.Course)/",
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (docs) {
            if(model == null)
            {
                model = new CourseDocumentModel(docs);
                ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("bindingDiv"));
            }
            else
            {
                model.reloadDocuments(docs);
            }

            if(uploadRow != null)
                $(uploadRow).fadeOut();

            refreshPopover();

            isBindingComplete = true;

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //alert("refreshGrid error status: " + xhr.status);
            //alert("refreshGrid error thrown: " + thrownError);
            isBindingComplete = true;
        } 
    });
}
```

I'm facing two issues here:

1. The deleteDocument method defined in the model CourseDocumentModel is automatically fired for the number of documents binded. I 'm not sure how this event is triggered when the ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("bindingDiv")) is executed from the regreshGrid method. So as a workaround I have used a flag to determine if the binding is completed or not
2. After binding, If I click the Delete button from the html code, the model function deleteDocument is not firing. I don't see any issues in the console (Firebug). I googled and found suggestion of $root.deleteDocument($data) but still the issue remains. Can you please guide me addressing the issue?

Thanks,
Hemant.

Comment: can you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X8Hnc/. I 'm new so I don't know exactly how to setup.

Comment: @Hemant Please include any external javascript files (jQuery, knockout etc) from the left pane that says "External Resources" in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Hi Friend, I have added the jQuery lib using external references and knockout library from the framework and extension section. But still not seeing any output. Not sure what I'm missing. Can you please check.

Comment: Try $parent.deleteDocument

Comment: Yes, I even tried $parent.deleteDocument and this is also not firing on click. When I tried $parent.deleteDocument($data), the deleteDocument is executed for every row binded when ko.applyBindings is executed but does not actually fire when the button is clicked. I 'm not sure if the binding are destroyed somehow or somewhere. Is there any tool or anything that is available to verify this. I tried Chrome's Knockout add-in and that is not providing any help. I tried to look into Firebug console and there too there is no javascript issue. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Your deleteDocument function accepts a parameter which you are not passing from the click binding. Try : <a class="tool tool-remove" href="#" data-bind="click:function() { $root.deleteDocument(null) }"> Delete</a>. You can pass the appropriate parameter value instead of null.

Comment: Yes, i tried by even passing null and $data but still the deleteDocument function defined within the model is not fired.